# Brouwer Degree is locally constant

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

I'm reading Milnor's book "Topology from the differential viewpoint" and I'm stuck at this point:

Let $M$ and $N$ be oriented n-dimensional manifolds without boundary and let
$$f: M \longrightarrow N$$
be a smooth map. If $M$ is compact and $N$ is connected it is asserted that the degree of $f$, $\deg(f,y)= \sum_{x \in f^{-1}(y)}\mathrm{sign} \ \mathrm{d}f_x$, is a locally constant function of $y$, as $y$ ranges through regular values. I'm not sure how to prove it but I have thought this:

We know that $\# f^{-1}(y)$ is locally constant and that the sign of $\det(\mathrm{d}f)$ (i.e $\mathrm{sign} \ \mathrm{d}f$) is locally constant too. So I guess that we can conlude the desired result from this. But I'm a little bit confused because I didn't use the fact that $N$ is connected... Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: $\det (df)$ is certainly not locally constant. Maybe you mean its sign? But the hypothesis that $N$ is connected is unnecessary. Any argument that works for connected $N$ can be done separately on each component of a disconnected $N$.

Comment: I'm really very sorry. You are right, of course I mean the sign! So the "machinery" I used is correct, right?

Comment: You're not done yet. To run your argument you need to show that as $y$ varies continuously, the $x \in f^{-1}(y)$ also vary continuously.

Comment: Can't we conclude this by proving that $\# f^{-1}(y)$ is locally constant? Since, during this proof, we can notice that if $f^{-1}(y)=\{x_1,...,x_p\}$ and as $y'$ ranges through values in a neighborhood of $y$ also do the points $x'_j$ in a neighborhood of $x_j$, where $f^{-1}(y)=\{x'_1,...,x'_p\}$.